# Rollbar ignore ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound exceptions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rollbar

I would like Rollbar to ignore uncaught exceptions `ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound` to save request pool in our plan. I did what they say in documentation:

```
config.exception_level_filters.merge!({
  "ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound" => "ignore"
})
```

but Rollbar still reports the errors in the API. How do I filter out those exceptions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Where do you have this code ? it should be in `config/initializers/` folder, typically something like `config/initializers/rollbar.rb`

Also they say, it will not affect these config if you are directly calling Rollbar via your code E.g `Rollbar.error(....)`

Your code looks correct according to the [documentation](https://github.com/rollbar/rollbar-gem#exception-level-filters)

You can check

1 ) - If you are calling Rollbar via your code directly

```
begin
  user = User.find(<id>)
rescue ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound => e
  Rollbar.error(exception) 
end
```

If so, do `Rollbar.error(exception, :use_exception_level_filters => true)`

2 ) Even though it seems silly, you haven't restarted the server after the change ¯_(ツ)_/¯ (had happened to me a lot..)

Comment: I have this config in `config/initializers/rollbar.rb`. I am not using direct calls to `Rollbar.error`. But I've just realized that I haven't restarted the server :D Damn :D

Comment: To add for future visitors, I eventually figured out that I was calling Rollbar.error(e) in our error handlers which was catching these types of errors so removing direct calls of Rollbar.error(e) fixed the problem.